# c++ linked list insert function

Tags: c++, linked-list

I get a compile error for a create function I use with the insert function. It works though when I do the different calls in the if clause, but I want to move it to a seperate create function instead. Any help  regarding the compile error I get is appreciated

|76|error: cannot convert `list_link*' to`sorted_list::list_link*' in assignment|

The header file

```
class sorted_list
{
public:
    sorted_list(); // Constructor declaration
    ~sorted_list(); // Destructor declaration

    void insert(int key, double value);
    void print();


private:
    class list_link
    {
        // Declarations
        public:
        my_key_type key;
        my_value_type value;
        list_link *next;
    };
    list_link* first;

};
```

The functions

```
void sorted_list::insert(int key, double value)
{
    list_link *curr, *prev;

    curr = first;

    while(curr)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(first == 0 || prev == 0) //if empty or add first
    {
        cout << "empty list" << endl;
        list_link *new_link = new list_link;
        new_link->key = key;
        new_link->value = value;
        new_link->next = 0;
        first = new_link;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "add" << endl;
        prev->next = create(key, value, 0);
    }
}
```

create function

```
list_link* create(my_key_type key, my_value_type value, list_link* next)
{
   // creates the node;
   list_link *new_link = new list_link;

   // add values to the node;
   new_link->key = key;
   new_link->value = value;
   new_link->next = next;

  return new_link;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `list_link` is:

1. Declared in the scope of `sorted_list`
2. Marked as `private`

In order to have a freestanding function create an object of this type, you will need to make the type public, and you will also need to either prefix it with `sorted_list::`, or you wil need to declare it outside of the `sorted_list` class. I should add that you use `list_link` as a simple data object, where there are no methods and the fields are public, and so -- from a purely stylistic perspective -- I would recommend declaring it as a `struct` instead of a class, which also removes the need for public.

Comment: is there's some other way, since I want to keep the Node creation internal to the class only

Comment: @starcorn, if it is internal, then don't use a freestanding function; make the create function a private function of sorted_list.

Comment: ah, that's what I thought but I kept struggeling with it for quite some time before I saw that I had to write sorted_list::list_link sorted_list::create() {} in the .cc file. Anyway I think I sorted it out now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not an authority in C++ but I think the problem comes with the way you are scpping things.

1. The `list_link` class is private. I recommend this being public since a class is only a blueprint through which object instances can be created. What you can keep private is the actual pointer to the linked list, `list_link *first`.
2. Since the `list_link` class is nested under the `sorted_list` class,  you have to go through the `sorted_list` scope each time you try to access the `list_link` class.

Try this out for a fix:

```
class sorted_list
{
public:
    sorted_list(); // Constructor declaration
    ~sorted_list(); // Destructor declaration

    void insert(int key, double value);
    void print();


    class list_link
    {
        // Declarations
        public:
        my_key_type key;
        my_value_type value;
        list_link *next;
    };
private:
    list_link* first;

};

sorted_list::list_link* create(my_key_type key, my_value_type value, sorted_list::list_link* next)
{
   // creates the node;
    sorted_list::list_link *new_link = new sorted_list::list_link;

   // add values to the node;
   new_link->key = key;
   new_link->value = value;
   new_link->next = next;

  return new_link;
}

void sorted_list::insert(int key, double value)
{
    list_link *curr, *prev;

    curr = first;

    while(curr)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(first == 0 || prev == 0) //if empty or add first
    {
        cout << "empty list" << endl;
        list_link *new_link = new list_link;
        new_link->key = key;
        new_link->value = value;
        new_link->next = 0;
        first = new_link;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "add" << endl;
        prev->next = create(key, value, 0);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.